# why there is an expectation in finding least square?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

There is the formula from wiki, $x_i^T$ is the i-th row of $X$

$$\color{blue}{S(b)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-x_i^Tb)^2=(Y-Xb)^T(Y-Xb)}$$ To find the least squared error $\hat{b}$ we rewrite the formula as $$\hat{b}:=argmin_{b\in\mathbb{R}^p}\| Y-Xb\|^2$$

All of above formulation I could understand, but I encounter a tutorial question asking the same thing but the formula as $$\hat{b}:=argmin_{b\in\mathbb{R}^p}\mathbb{E} \{(Y-Xb)^2\}$$

I would like to know where is this expectation originally comes from?

Thank you for any help and comments

---

**Edited** Please help me out with this

The blue equation is what I usually write out when I am doing least square, even for this question I would change the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ into $\frac{\sum(\cdot)}{N}$, however, this way my lecturer says it is not correct, he said this is the sample estimation( He explained something but I still do not get it). what really confused me is if you have an expectation there, I would think about those are population parameter, how is that possible to minimise the population parameter, they exist (but we do not know, we can only use the sample to estimate) and **unique**, we are not having a bunch of estimated to find out the least square for the population parameter.

Is the solution of $argmin_{b\in\mathbb{R}^p}\mathbb{E}\{(Y-Xb)^2\}$ should be different from $argmin_{b\in\mathbb{R}^p}S(b)$

FOC condition:

$$\mathbb{E}\{2(XY-X'X\hat{b})\}=0\\\mathbb{E}(\hat{b})=\mathbb{E}(XY)^{-1}\mathbb{E}(X'X)$$

Comment: The sum at the top is simply the sample analog of the expectation at the bottom (up to the scaling factor $n$).

Comment: @WillMarble Thank you for your reply. Do we just ignore $\frac{1}{N}$ at the top for simplicity?

Comment: Yes. The value of $b$ that minimizes $\sum (y - x'b)^2$ is the same as the one that minimizes $\frac{1}{n} \sum (y- x'b)^2$.

Comment: To me this makes no sense. What Expectation is minimized?

Comment: @Sextus I make sense of this by viewing everything abstractly as a vector.  In the first case these are data vectors (columns); in the second case $Y$ and $Xb$ are random variables and the expectation (actually, the expectation conditional on $X$) of the squared difference is a Euclidean distance in the space of equivalence classes of almost surely equal RVs. Thus, both situations are finding the shortest distance between $Y$ and the subspace generated by $X.$ The latter could be considered a "population regression:" it is a property of the joint random variable $(X,Y).$

Comment: @whuber ah, I was thinking something like that but it sounds strange* and confusing. So we consider the expectation of the square of a random residual out of the n residuals in the sample. (*it is strange because then we think of the concept of a 'random residual' which seems a bit artificial to me) (it is confusing because the expectation can mean various other things, e.g. the expectation of the squared error is reduced when we apply shrinking or some other bias)

Comment: @Sextus I think the intended way to understand the second formulation is not in terms of a sample: this is regression *of a bivariate distribution.*  The standard example is Binormal $(X,Y)$ (for the case $p=1$).

Answer (score 1):

Answering with a question, how would you minimize a *function of random variables $X$ and $Y$*? Say that $Y$ is Gaussian, so it can take any value between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, what does *argmin* mean in this context? The expectation is one way of solving this problem because you precisely state that you minimize the expected value, rather than the random variable, whatever would that mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your answer is somewhat similar to what my lecturer explained to me. Yes, minimised the expected value, is that sufficient to write the answer as the expected value of something?  (By linearity of expectation and derivative, find out $b$ in terms of expectation of sth?)

Comment: @LJNG I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I've re-edited the post. Are those two equations (one with expectation, the other is in $\sum$ form)are different in meaning? Also, would they have different solutions? Does my solution $\mathbb{E}(\hat{b})$ look good to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the instructor so I don't know what your instructor intended by this, but there is a population analogue of the least squares problem that sheds light on what linear regression is trying to achieve, and draws a connection between population/sample mean and the least squares estimator. Going back to the decision-theoretic justification of using mean as the "best guess," the population version proceeds sequentially as follows.

1. We need to pick one number $c$ in place of $Y$ that minimizes the mean squared error $\mathbb{E}((Y-c)^2)$. By the simple trick $\mathbb{E}((Y - \mathbb{E}(Y) + \mathbb{E}(Y) -c)^2)$, we can easily see that the MSE is a quadratic function of $c$, where the minimum $\mathbb{E}((Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))^2)$ is attained when $c = \mathbb{E}(Y)$.
2. Now, let's extend the problem where additional information $X$ is available. The problem is then to minimize $\mathbb{E}((Y-c(X))^2\mid X)$ where after observing $X=x$, our prediction becomes $c(x)$. By the same logic, this conditional MSE is minimized when $c(x)=\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X=x)$.
3. This time, let's give $c(X)$ some structure. Let's say $c(X) = a + bX$. This is precisely the case of a linear prediction, and the minimizers are
   $$
   b = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\mathrm{Var}(X)}=\frac{\rho\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X},\quad a= \mu_Y-a\mu_X.
   $$
   The best prediction is $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X=x) = \mu_Y + \rho\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)$.

Do you see the connection between the population version of linear prediction and a simple linear regression? This resemblance carries over to the multivariate case where $X$ is a matrix and $y$ is a vector. Ordinary least squares problem is the sample version of this, where the expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ is with respect to the empirical measure, i.e., $\mathbb{E}f = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, genuinely. To be honest, I don't see the difference in solution. OLS is the sample version of this, aren't they have the same solutions? I mean, the solution for OLS (simple linear ) also have exactly the same $a, b$